# Detailed changelog between minor QGIS version

Tags: qgis

How can I know in detail what fixes have been applied to a certain new QGIS version?

**For example: what has been changed between QGIS 2.14.02 -> QGIS 2.14.03?**

I know of the [visual changelog](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog214/), that gives a great overview of the large picture for 2.12 -> 2.14.

The answer is probably in the [QGIS issues pages](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues).

---

@Joseph commented on the possibility to get the changelog from GitHub. Actually you get a good idea of the commits between versions by looking at the branch you are interested in, for example:
[For QGIS 2.14](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_14/ChangeLog) -> Then, viewing the raw file you can find "Release of 2.14.2", "Release of 2.14.1"... and in between the comments of the different commits that happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, Github is indeed the best place to see which fixes made it into a bug fix release, but I would look at [the commits list](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commits/release-2_14) rather than the raw file linked in the question, because it's easier to read:

[image]